# SVD of symmetric but indefinite matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, svd, symmetric-matrices

The SVD of the matrix $A$ is $A = U \Sigma V^T$, where $A\in R^{m\times n}$ is symmetric positive definite or semi positive definite matrix and $U$ and $V$ are square orthogonal matrices.

Does $A$ has to be positive or semi positive? If $A\in R^{n\times n}$ is symmetric but indefinite can we still have a SVD?
Also if $A\in R^{m\times n}$ but $U$ and $V$ are not orthogonal will $A$ and $UAV$ still have same singular values?

Basicaly I want to understand if we can have SVD for *any* matrix and if the case when $A$ is symmetric positive definite with orthogonal eigenvectos just a special case of SVD?

Comment: If $A$ is $m \times n$ and $m \ne n$, it **can't** be symmetric.

Comment: In that question it is stated that $A\in R^{nxn}$

Comment: In the first line it says $m \times n$.

Answer (score 1):

SVD decomposition exists for any real matrices. No other additional requirement is needed. $\Sigma$ share the same size as $A$ and $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices.

As for your another question when $U$ and $V$ need not be orthogonal, not true in general, for example if you let $U=0$ then the singular value is just $0$.

When a matrix is symmetric, we know that it has an eigenvalue decomposition, that is you can pick $U$ and $V$ to be the same orthogonal matrix.