# Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be symmetric but indefinite. Determine an SVD of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

Note, the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978723/svd-of-symmetric-but-indefinite-matrix) answered the question that SVD's exists for all matrices. The post did not answer what such one might be for this particular question.

We know that $A$ (in our case) will have positive and negative eigenvalues. In addition, we know that all symmetric matrices can be decomposed by the [eigenvector decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) theorem that is
$$A=Q\Lambda Q^T$$
Where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix matrix containing the eigenvalues for $A$ and $Q$ contains the linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$. Now using this equation, I am unsure how to manipulate it so that
$$A = (\text{"orthogonal matrix"})\Sigma(\text{"orthogonal matrix"}).$$
Note that the "orthogonal matrix" are of compatible size. I was given a hint to find an equation that satifsifes
$$A = (QD^{-1})(D\Lambda)Q^T$$
Where $\Sigma = D\Lambda$? I am not sure though. Any advice is much helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $D$ to be a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are either $1$ or $-1$, so that $D\Lambda$ becomes diagonal with nonnegative diagonal entries. $D^{-1}$ will similarly negate the columns of $Q$ corresponding to the negative eigenvalues. Check that $QD^{-1}$ is still orthogonal.

Comment: I like it. One question though, is not each $\sigma_i = \sqrt{\lambda_i}$? If so, how do we account for this? Does it even matter in this case?

Comment: @Owen The $\lambda_i$ in the "$\sigma_i = \sqrt{\lambda_i}$" statement is referring to the eigenvalues of $A^\top A$ (in general when $A$ need not be square), not the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Ok gotcha! That makes sense! Thanks you!